# Updating a cell in google sheets when another cell is updated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Googlesheet that is linked to a form. I am looking to get the column named  "MSP" to update to say "SRM" when the column "Team Escalation is sat with" equals Request. I can create this if statement very easily in the Googlesheet Cell, however. Because the form is linked to the sheet, even though "team escalation is sat with" is a column that is not populated by the sheet, it is overwritten when the row is populated with data from the sheet and turns into a blank cell with no IF statement appended anymore. Due to this I am trying to carry this out in script. I have the below but I am clearly getting something wrong. Any help would be great

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (sheet.getName() == "Form responses 1") {
    //"Form responses 1" is the name of the sheet
var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var mspCol = headers[0].indexOf("MSP");
var nswCol = headers[0].indexOf("Escalation is now sat with ");

if (mspCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && editColumn == nswCol && nswCol=="Request") {
     sheet
     .getRange(rowIndex, mspCol)
.setValue(mspCol= "SRM");
   }}}
```

Comment: What's not working? Any error messages you getting or just not getting the expected result?

Comment: Hi @New_2_Code , unfortunately nothing at all :( no error messages etc. very strange. unsure what im missing. Have triple checked the variable names and they are all correct. Have even checked pre and post update of the row by the form which also makes no difference

Comment: I would then investigate your second if statement. By the sounds of it not all criteria is being met. Be sure to use the debugging tool to make sure the values of the variables are what you expect them to be. Also make sure you are using the correct comparison operators. It's important to remember the code will only do what you tell it to do.

Comment: @RWLY Have you resolved your problem, or are you still in need of help?

Comment: Hi @tedinoz thanks for getting back to me, I have managed to resolve it. I will close the question now